# What is the field type for a file in a Mongodb Schema/Model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using a Mongo Schema to post a form. Works well with all strings but now I'm trying to upload a file. What type of field should I specify the file would be in the Schema?

```
//create model/schema
const TrackSchema = new Schema({
    title:{
        type: String, 
        required: true
    },
    length:{
        type: String, 
        required: true
    }, 
    available:{
        type: Boolean, 
        required: true
    },
    image:{
        type: String, 
        required: true
    }, 
    date: {
        type: Date, 
        default: Date.now
    }, 
    source: {
        type: **??, 
        required: true
    }
})
```

What type should I make the 'source' field which will be a file coming from the form

Answer (score 5):

It really depends on your use-case -- specifically with what constraints you are dealing with.

I can think of two ways of doing this:

1. Store it as a `type: Buffer`.
2. Store it as a `type: String` in `base64`.

Storing it as a `Buffer` may be the most efficient way to store it with regards to space/speed. It also gives you the flexibility to convert it to whatever type is needed for your use-case.

Storing it as a `String` will give you easier control of the file contents when you need to access it for downloading because you won't need to convert from `Buffer` to `base64`.

Personally I like to store files as a `Buffer`and tack on other necessary fields such as `filename` and `mimetype` which would yield something like:

```
source: {
        file: { type: Buffer, required: true },
        filename: { type: String, required: true },
        mimetype: { type: String, required: true }
      }
```

...but this is also specific to my use-cases.

There is also a 3rd option of storing it using `GridFS` in mongo in case your files exceed the 16MB filesize. You can read more about that in their official documentation page: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you store the file data to a database (if, at all, you're storing a file).

There are ways to store the file data.

1. Your file size is less than 16 MB. You can store the data directly to collection in buffer(Binary data).

   ```
   source : { data: Buffer, contentType: String }
   ```
2. In case the file size is more than 16MB, you can use [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#when-to-use-gridfs).
3. You store the file on disk and just store the path to mongodb collection. In this case, the type would just be string.